# Fatal error: unable to initialize JIT - R 3.5.1 and RStudio 1.4463

Tags: r, 64-bit, rstudio, fatal-error

I recently decided to upgrade both R and RStudio on my PC, 64-bit version. 
First, I uninstalled the previous versions, RStudio 1.4462 and R 3.4.4, and then I installed R 3.5.1 and RStudio 1.4463, in the order here mentioned.
The installation goes just fine, but when I try to open R from the desktop shortcut I receive an error message saying:

> Fatal error - unable to initialize JIT

The same thing happens with RStudio.
I click OK on the message (it's the only thing I can do) and R closes immediately, same for RStudio.

What could cause this issue? I looked around the internet but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: I also have the same issue. The only difference I have is, when I open R Studio/R for the first time it works perfectly fine. When I close it and try to open again, it gives me the error. If I open R (32 bit) it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the cause of the JIT error, but in case anyone stumbles upon this thread later, I was able to overcome this issue by reinstalling the same version of R (4.1.0 in my case) on my machine, overwriting the old version. Doing so seemed to maintain all my previously installed packages too. Now R & Rstudio works fine on start-up. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. I tried launching rstudio ("Desert Sunflower" Release for RHEL 8) with a different version of R (v4.0.0) than I normally do (v4.3.1) from a conda environment and got the same JIT error as you. I tried a bunch of different solutions (most forums online suggested resetting Rstudio's state) and none of them worked. Then it occurred to me that *the version of R and Rstudio I was using may have been incompatible with one another*. I tried a conda environment with a different version of R (v4.2.0) and it worked! I hope this helps you or someone else like me facing this issue.